# Percentile values Proc rank Sas

Tags: sas, rank, percentile

I know how to compute the rank/percentile of an observation in SAS.

Here is what I do:

```
data have;
input group $ variable;
datalines;
a 1
a 3
a 4 
a 5
a 4 
a 7 
b 4
b 4
b 2
b 8 
b 9
b 7;

proc sort data out=data;
by group;
run;

proc rank data groups 3 out=data;
by group;
rank r_variable;
var variable;
run;
```

This adds a r_variable column to the table. In addition to that, I would like a column that contains the value of the respective percentile, i.e. the value of the 33th and 66th percentile.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To better understand how to write a good question and get relevant answers, please read our [Welcome Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to and [How ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) articles.

Comment: How are you computing the rank/percentile ?  Did you use `Proc RANK` ?

Comment: Yes, I do use proc rank

Comment: In your question, you should show your code and provide a sample data and a sample of the desired output. Otherwise, we wil have to be guessing to try to help you. Please read the tutorial recommended in the first comment. If I understood your quetion, you just need to specify the output data: `proc rank data=have out=want groups=100; `